# How to add text with a property transfer in soapUI

Tags: web-services, groovy, soapui

I have a test suite in soapUI which has two test cases.

- First test case has a payment request that has a Account No for example, 2356698.
- The second request that I have is about creating a Autopay (recurring) Profile for the customer. In the request one of the elements is accountID with letters on it. Like this,  2356698REC.

Is there any way, I can do a property transfer and add those three letters REC after the account no. Considering I have to perform the test multiple times so the accountID will change every time. So I would like take the accountID from first request and transfer it to the second request but also want to add REC to it.

Is that possible through a property transfer or a groovy script?
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope a test case might have been created in the soapui project.

Add two SOAP request steps, you might have them already. Not required a property transfer or groovy script steps in between the two request steps.

For the first request, add the [Script Assertion](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html) with following code:

```
//Check if there is response
assert context.response, 'Response is empty'

//provide the element name which data you need to extract, in this case accountId
def requiredElement = 'accountId'

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)

//extract account id value from xml
def accountIdValue = xml.'**'.find{it.name() == requiredElement}?.text()

//Store at test case level custom property
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('ACCOUNT_ID', accountIdValue)
```

In the second request, do the below change :
This assumes that element name is `AccountId`, you can change as needed to suite your need.

```
<AccountId>${#TestCase#ACCOUNT_ID}REC</AccountId>
```

When the request is sent, soapui replaces with first steps extracted value in the second request.

Even the above can be done with the help of `Property transfer`. Save the value to test case and use it as mentioned above for the second step with REC and property expansion.